# AngularJS hiding #! with rewriting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-rewriting, url-routing

Lets say we have a website build on AngularJS. We figure out how to hide not pretty `/#!/` characters from url by setting HTML5mode on true. But we have a problem when visitor came to the website with old url link including `/#!/` i.e. `www.example.com/#!/products/` it redirect him to homepage `www.example.com` which of course we didn't meant we expected to redirect him to `www.example.com/products/` so we tried write many rewrite rules which says, that if you go to website through old link with `/#!/` than it should redirect you to the new link without  `/#!/`. But this doesn't work for us and we are sure rewrites rules has been OK.

Can be there some problem with AngularJS setting? 
Thanks for your time and advices!

Comment: which server side language are you using

Comment: @oseintow — That should be irrelevant. The data is only available client side code in the first place.

Comment: Yea its irrelevant in your case because you have decoupled the client side from the server. I agree

Comment: @oseintow — No, because that's just how fragment identifiers in URLs work.

Comment: With all the apps i have written with angular which are coupled with the server side language i use the server side to redirect all missing pages for angular to handle. example in php is as follows.  if($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException)
        {
            return response()->view("index")->header('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        }    and we add this <base href="/"> to the html

Comment: We have in HTML <base href="/">

Answer (score 2):

Fragment identifiers are never sent to the server, so you can't deal with them using server side code (including rewriting). You have to process them with client side code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, but I´m not 100% sure how does it work and I would like to know it. All I need to do was add `hashPrefix('!')` behind setting of html5Mode.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
```

Now it works as we wanted, but what `hashPrefix('!')` actually do? I just found from documentation that it "*Configure existing providers*" but why hiding of `#!` works without this?

Please can you explain me my last two questions about this topic. Thank you